# how to modify django ImageField to accept svg files

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using django rest framework(version 3.12.2) for my backend, and React/Next js in my front end.

my goal is pretty straightforward, I want to upload images to photo_main field.

unfortunately I receive an error message when trying to upload svg images (png,jpg and jpeg are working just fine)

**the err msg**

```
{"photo_main":["Upload a valid image. The file you uploaded was either not an image or a corrupted image."]}
```

**the model**

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField( 
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False,
    )
    author = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model() , on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='author') 
    photo_main = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/', blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Good question, and reasonable, but svg's aren't considered images in most contexts.  You should look at rest_framework.fields.ImageField and then create your own custom field for your serializer, and use FileField for your model.  Its more work, but this is a custom scenario that requires it.  Validating file extensions is not recommended - user input can't be trusted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after browsing the forum I came across the solution:

**validators.py**

```
import os
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def validate_file_extension(value):
    ext = os.path.splitext(value.name)[1]  # [0] returns path+filename
    valid_extensions = ['.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.svg']
    if not ext.lower() in valid_extensions:
        raise ValidationError('Unsupported file extension.')
```

**models.py**

```
from app_name.valiators import validate_file_extension

image = models.ImageField('Image', upload_to=image_upload_path, validators=[validate_file_extension])
```

Comment: This only worked for me when using a FileField instead of an ImageField as it checks the uploaded image with PIL, which breaks for SVG. (Django 3.2)